# Change dex file - apk

Tags: android, decompiling

I am looking for a way to make changes to my apk file - These changes should make the apk harder to reverse engineer.

I am already running Proguard to obfuscate the code.

From what I see there are Dexguard and Dexprotect that add encryption for your classes and resources. Is there a simple way to add encryption by your self to the resource folder?

I have also found from old answers HoseDex2Jar. This tool will protect your code from decompiling. The answers were 4 years old and now I could not find this tool. The website is still online but it seems that they have redesigned their software. Is there a new solution like this?

On Jelly Bean it seems that you can encrypt the apk. But it only works if you install the apk from adb - so it can not be used in production(where users download the app from google play)
https://nelenkov.blogspot.ro/2012/07/using-app-encryption-in-jelly-bean.html

Thanks